# How to combine these two moving pictures together?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I have plotted separately two graphics, and I cannot use show to combine them together because this would disturb the moving pattern. I don't know How to do this. 
By the way, how to draw another ball rotating the opposite direction in the same picture so that there are two oppositely rotating balls?

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
  Red, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {0, 0, 2}}, 0.04]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0.3, 0, -1.2}, {0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3, 0, -1.2}, {-0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0.3, -1.2}, {0, 0.8, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0, -0.3, -1.2}, {0, -0.8, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, 
      0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, 
      0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/
       2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
  Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/
       2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]]}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0., 0.1, 0.01], {1, 0, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.605, 0.2, 0.1], {0.5, 0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.61, 0.205, 0.1], {0, 1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.615, 0.21, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.62, 0.215, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.625, 0.22, 0.1], {-0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.63, 0.225, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
    RGBColor[0.635, 0.23, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> 
  Dynamic[RotationTransform[Clock[{2 \[Pi], 0}, 5], {0, 0, 1}][{1, 0, 
     0}]], PlotRange -> 5, SphericalRegion -> True]

ParametricPlot3D[{x = 1.5 Cos[10 t], y = 1.5 Sin[10 t], 
  z = t}, {t, -1.2, 1.2}]
```

Following is the one that I don't want. I don't want the spiral curve to move anyway.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
   Red, Arrowheads[0.02], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 1.5}, {0, 0, 2}}, 0.04]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3, 0, -1.2}, {0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3, 0, -1.2}, {-0.8, 0, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0.3, -1.2}, {0, 0.8, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, -0.3, -1.2}, {0, -0.8, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, 
       0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, 0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/2,
        0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {0.8 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]],
   Blue, Arrowheads[0.01], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{-0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -0.3 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.2}, {-0.8 Sqrt[2]/
        2, -0.8 Sqrt[2]/2, -1.7}}, 0.003]]}, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0., 0.1, 0.01], {1, 0, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.605, 0.2, 0.1], {0.5, 0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.61, 0.205, 0.1], {0, 1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.615, 0.21, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.62, 0.215, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.625, 0.22, 0.1], {-0.5, -0.5, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.63, 0.225, 0.1], {0, -1, 0}}, {"Directional", 
     RGBColor[0.635, 0.23, 0.1], {0.5, -0.5, 0}}}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> 
   Dynamic[RotationTransform[Clock[{2 \[Pi], 0}, 5], {0, 0, 1}][{1, 0,
       0}]], PlotRange -> 5, SphericalRegion -> True], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x = 1.5 Cos[10 t], y = 1.5 Sin[10 t], 
   z = t}, {t, -1.2, 1.2}]]
```

[image]
I want a static spiral curve and a rotating ball on the left with static arrows and an oppositely rotating ball on the right.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want the result to look like, but my guess is that you need to use: `Show[Graphics3D[Dynamic[Rotate[{Sphere[...],...Arrow[...],..., },Clock[{0,2pi},5],{0,0,1}],..], ParametricPlot3D[...] ]` to rotate the graphics instead of the view point.

Comment: I want a static spiral curve and a rotating ball on the left with static arrows and an oppositely rotating ball on the right.

Comment: How to rotate a ball?

Comment: Related: [Animate a circle “rolling” along a complicated 3D curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129562/animate-a-circle-rolling-along-a-complicated-3d-curve).

Comment: @corey979  I think that is not what I need.

Comment: As long as the ball is inside `Rotate` it is rotating, you just can't see it because it's all the same color. Try adding the `latitude` function used in the accepted answer on: [98798](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98798/to-change-the-pattern-of-sphere-surface-in-graphic3d).

Comment: @ZHANG Juenjie, as for the opposite rotating ball, you can use the same code but with your clock going backward, `Clock[{2Pi, 0},5]`.